How to read a file from an external usb drive connected to android, java solution
I have a React Native application where I need to find a specific file, DataXYZ.txt, when an external USB device is connected and be able to share it. Since, to my knowledge, React Native does not provide such features, I decided to write a module in Java. However, I couldn't figure it out. Could you please help?
Here is the module that checks if the device is connected; I need help extending it.
package com.awesomeproject.usb;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.LifecycleEventListener;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class UsbDeviceListenerModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements LifecycleEventListener {

    private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
    private final BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver;
    private boolean isInitialized = false;

    public UsbDeviceListenerModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;

        // Регистрация слушателя жизненного цикла
        reactContext.addLifecycleEventListener(this);

        usbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
                    UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    if (device != null) {
                        sendDeviceConnectedEvent(device);
                    }
                } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
                    UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    if (device != null) {
                        sendDeviceDisconnectedEvent(device);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // Регистрация ресивера для прослушивания подключений и отключений
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
        reactContext.registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "UsbDeviceListener";
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        super.invalidate();
        // Отмена регистрации ресивера при уничтожении модуля
        reactContext.unregisterReceiver(usbReceiver);
        reactContext.removeLifecycleEventListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHostResume() {
        if (!isInitialized) {
            checkForConnectedUsbDevices();
            isInitialized = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onHostPause() {
        // Не требуется действия при паузе
    }

    @Override
    public void onHostDestroy() {
        // Не требуется действия при уничтожении
    }

    private void checkForConnectedUsbDevices() {
        UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) reactContext.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = usbManager.getDeviceList();
        if (!deviceList.isEmpty()) {
            for (UsbDevice device : deviceList.values()) {
                sendDeviceConnectedEvent(device);
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendDeviceConnectedEvent(UsbDevice device) {
        WritableMap deviceData = Arguments.createMap();
        deviceData.putString("deviceName", device.getDeviceName());
        deviceData.putInt("vendorId", device.getVendorId());
        deviceData.putInt("productId", device.getProductId());
        deviceData.putInt("deviceClass", device.getDeviceClass());
        deviceData.putInt("deviceSubclass", device.getDeviceSubclass());
        deviceData.putInt("deviceProtocol", device.getDeviceProtocol());

        if (reactContext.hasActiveCatalystInstance()) {
            reactContext
                .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit("UsbDeviceConnected", deviceData);
        }
    }

    private void sendDeviceDisconnectedEvent(UsbDevice device) {
        WritableMap deviceData = Arguments.createMap();
        deviceData.putString("deviceName", device.getDeviceName());

        if (reactContext.hasActiveCatalystInstance()) {
            reactContext
                .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit("UsbDeviceDisconnected", deviceData);
        }
    }
}



The module you shared detects when a USB device is connected or disconnected by using "BroadcastReceiver". The next step is to look through the USB device’s storage to find the file named DataXYZ.txt. If we find it, we can create an intent that tells android that we want to share this file. We can show a list of apps that can handle the file, and the user can choose one to share the file. Here is the extended code:
package com.awesomeproject.usb;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.LifecycleEventListener;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class UsbDeviceListenerModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements LifecycleEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = "UsbDeviceListener";
    private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
    private final BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver;
    private boolean isInitialized = false;

    public UsbDeviceListenerModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;

        // Регистрация слушателя жизненного цикла
        reactContext.addLifecycleEventListener(this);

        usbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
                    UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    if (device != null) {
                        sendDeviceConnectedEvent(device);
                        findAndShareFile(device);
                    }
                } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
                    UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    if (device != null) {
                        sendDeviceDisconnectedEvent(device);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // Регистрация ресивера для прослушивания подключений и отключений
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
        reactContext.registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "UsbDeviceListener";
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        super.invalidate();
        // Отмена регистрации ресивера при уничтожении модуля
        reactContext.unregisterReceiver(usbReceiver);
        reactContext.removeLifecycleEventListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHostResume() {
        if (!isInitialized) {
            checkForConnectedUsbDevices();
            isInitialized = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onHostPause() {
        // Не требуется действия при паузе
    }

    @Override
    public void onHostDestroy() {
        // Не требуется действия при уничтожении
    }

    private void checkForConnectedUsbDevices() {
        UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) reactContext.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = usbManager.getDeviceList();
        if (!deviceList.isEmpty()) {
            for (UsbDevice device : deviceList.values()) {
                sendDeviceConnectedEvent(device);
                findAndShareFile(device);
            }
        }
    }

    private void findAndShareFile(UsbDevice device) {
        File usbDirectory = new File("/storage");

        if (usbDirectory.exists() && usbDirectory.isDirectory()) {
            File file = searchFileInDirectory(usbDirectory, "DataXYZ.txt");

            if (file != null && file.exists()) {
                shareFile(file);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "DataXYZ.txt not found on USB device: " + device.getDeviceName());
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "USB directory not found or is not a directory");
        }
    }

    private File searchFileInDirectory(File directory, String fileName) {
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();

        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    File foundFile = searchFileInDirectory(file, fileName);
                    if (foundFile != null) {
                        return foundFile;
                    }
                } else if (fileName.equalsIgnoreCase(file.getName())) {
                    return file;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void shareFile(File file) {
        Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share file via");

        chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        reactContext.startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }

    private void sendDeviceConnectedEvent(UsbDevice device) {
        WritableMap deviceData = Arguments.createMap();
        deviceData.putString("deviceName", device.getDeviceName());
        deviceData.putInt("vendorId", device.getVendorId());
        deviceData.putInt("productId", device.getProductId());
        deviceData.putInt("deviceClass", device.getDeviceClass());
        deviceData.putInt("deviceSubclass", device.getDeviceSubclass());
        deviceData.putInt("deviceProtocol", device.getDeviceProtocol());

        if (reactContext.hasActiveCatalystInstance()) {
            reactContext
        .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit("UsbDeviceConnected", deviceData);
        }
    }

    private void sendDeviceDisconnectedEvent(UsbDevice device) {
        WritableMap deviceData = Arguments.createMap();
        deviceData.putString("deviceName", device.getDeviceName());

        if (reactContext.hasActiveCatalystInstance()) {
            reactContext
        .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit("UsbDeviceDisconnected", deviceData);
        }
    }
}

Make sure to add the :"READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission and any other necessary permissions. Additionally, you need to update the file location.

thank you so much for responding, but what if we don't know the directory?
File usbDirectory = new File("/storage");
I would just like to contact you to find out the way to the device.
